# How to set up an examples folder with Turborepo and pnpm?

Tags: pnpm, turborepo

I have a Turborepo + pnpm monorepo with two folders: `/apps` and `/packages`.
It's working great and I wanted to add an `/examples` folder that would host a few examples of my package in use, but that don't need to share any dependencies with the monorepo. When I try to run `pnpm install` within one of the examples, ex: `/examples/blog`, instead of creating node_modules all I get is: `Scope: all 6 workspace projects`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There are some things need to be checked here:

- In the root `package.json` file, there is a field `workspaces`, it should contain your new folder name, in this case, is `examples`.
- Run `pnpm install` after you create the `examples` folder.
- In your `examples/package.json` file, make sure the `name` is unique across all workspaces.

Then you will be good to go.