# How to run pnpm on a nested folder that is _not_ part of workspace setup?

Tags: monorepo, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

How can I run pnpm on a nested package that is *not* supposed to be part of a workspace inside a monorepo? Say I have

```
root
├── packages
│   ├── foo
│   └── bar
├── non-workspaced-packages  
│   └── baz
├── pnpm-workspace.yaml
…
```

And a pnpm-workspace.yaml:

```
packages:
   - 'packages/**'
```

If I go into non-workspaced-packages/baz and hit `pnpm install` it still runs in the context of the root workspace. I can't seem to find a way to run pnpm in a folder nested inside something with a .pnpm-workspace.yaml without pnpm wanting to do the workspace thing…?

Related - I think this was the same question but in that case was misunderstood: [How to set up an examples folder with Turborepo and pnpm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73569046/how-to-set-up-an-examples-folder-with-turborepo-and-pnpm/74410157)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the `--ignore-workspace` flag:

```
pnpm --ignore-workspace install
```

I found it in [this GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/orgs/pnpm/discussions/4735#discussioncomment-2770033). I'm not sure why it isn't documented.